# Null Pointer Exception at line json.getInt("success")

Tags: php, android, json

i'm new in android programming and currently developing an apps that requires connection between android and mysql database. I'm done with connection part in php and android but it has nullpointer error when getting success tag. I dunno what's wrong but i do believe it is because fail in connection...any help please

get_bus_data.php:

```
<?php

$response = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

if (isset($_POST["busid"])) {

$busid = $_POST['busid'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM busstop1 WHERE busid = $busid");

if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $bus = array();
        $bus["Bus"] = $result["busid"];
        $bus["Time"] = $result["TimeSchedule"];

        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["Schedule"] = array();

        array_push($response["Schedule"], $bus);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No schedule found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No schedule found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}else {

// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);}
?>
```

db_connect.php

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT {

// constructor
function __construct() {
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // closing db connection
    $this->close();
}

function connect() {
    // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or  die(mysql_error());

    // Selecing database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or    die(mysql_error());

    // returing connection cursor
    return $con;
}

function close() {
    // closing db connection
    mysql_close();
}

}

?>
```

httpUrlConnectionParser.java

```
public class HttpUrlConnectionParser {
public static JSONObject jObj = null;
public static InputStream is=null;
public static String json = "";
public static HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

public HttpUrlConnectionParser(){
}

public static JSONObject makehttpUrlConnection(String url_path,HashMap<String,String> data) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_path);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQueryData(data));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        urlConnection.connect();
        is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;


            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = sb.toString();
            is.close();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    try{
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jObj;
}

public static String getQueryData(HashMap<String,String>data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result =  new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry:data.entrySet()){
        if(first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(),"UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(),"UTF-8"));

    }

    return result.toString();
}

}
```

testactivity.java

```
public class testactivity extends Activity {

private TextView test2;
Button test;
private HashMap<String,String> data;
private String url = "http://192.168.1.13/android_connect/get_bus_data.php";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testactivity);
    test2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test2);
    test = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_get);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new GetBookDataTask().execute();

        }
    });

}

private class GetBookDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(testactivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("busid", "101");

        try {

            JSONObject json = HttpUrlConnectionParser.makehttpUrlConnection(url, data);
            int succ = json.getInt("success");

            if (succ == 0) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                JSONArray jsonArray=json.getJSONArray("Schedule");
                JSONObject child=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                final String ans=child.optString("Time");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        test2.setText(ans.toString());
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of php should be like this:

```
{"success":1,"Schedule":[{"Bus":"101","Time":"10:30"}]}
```

Comment: have you checked output that you are getting  in java is same to that of php?

Comment: What output  are you getting when you access the url from web browser?

Comment: @Vivek The output cannot process as it have error at this line:int succ = json.getInt("success");

Comment: @Aamir The result is as shown as the output of php that i attached, but this is the result i get by hard coding the parameter in the php script, in normal case, value should pass from apps

Comment: Have you tried int succ=json.optInt(success); ??

Comment: @Aamir oh it works! but now i have another problem: NullPointerException lock == null, comes from line  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8); in httpUrlParser.java, seem like "is" return null but i thought i do get it using getInputStream(); ?

Comment: You should always check the instance/ java object is not null before using it anytime. You can try : if(is!=null){//todo your work here with "is"}